# How to get pin intents from smart card or token?

Tags: certificate, token, smartcard

Does anyone know how to get the number of PIN attempts a smartcard or token. NET or C / C + +?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only standardized way (ISO 7816-4) is, to send a VERIFY command. If the card responds 63Cx, then x is the number of retries. If it doesn't, a proprietary command may exist to find out. But there is no generic command and there is no other way than to look into the manual of the smartcard or token.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I suspected but did not want to believe.. :-(